# Blank page wordpress creating theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating theme in wordpress and I have encountered blank index page error.

```
I think that the problem is in closing html and body tags but I am not sure.

`<!--Header.php file-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php blog_info('charset');?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php blog_info('name');?></title>
        <?php wp_head();?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class();?>>

    <div class="container">
        <header class="site-header">
            <h1><a href"<?php echo home_url();?>"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a></h1>
            <h5><?php bloginfo('description');?></h5>
        </header>`

`<!--Footer.php file-->
<footer class="site-footer">
    <p><?php bloginfo('name');?> - &copy; <?php echo date('Y')?></p>
</footer>

<?php wp_head();?>
</div> <!-- closing div container -->
</body>
</html>`

`
<!--Index.php file-->
<h1>Hello world!</h1>

<?php

get_header();

if (have_posts()):
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
        <?php the_content();?>
    </article>

<?php endwhile;

    else : 
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;

get_footer();

?>`


In my webpage only the Hello world! is showing.
```

I tried deleting everything in header.php file and footer.php file, then suddenly it worked, but when I add something in these files I have blank page error. Can anyone provide me with solution? Would be thankful. <3

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I wrote blog_info instead of bloginfo. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

why you are using wp_head() function in footer.php user wp_footer() function in footer.php. All other seems to be fine.

If still the issue doesn't get solved. Try removing code from all three files one by one and check which file is causing the issue and then start removing the functions in code line by line to check which function causing the issue.